# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined - node.js - url params

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, url, parameters

I am trying to get certain params from my client-side get request (which come from user input), to feed into an API get a request I send off on my server.

I get this error when using .get on my search_params variable. I am using the 'URL' node.js package.

not sure why it is undefined I followed this guide to work out a solution to what I am trying to solve - [1](https://usefulangle.com/post/91/nodejs-get-url-parameters)

Code below: (I commented out the two lines that are causing the error so it is easier for you to see)

```
const axios = require('axios');
const router = require('express').Router();
const url = require('url');
require('dotenv').config();

const bamboo_api_key = process.env.BAMBOO_API_KEY;

const config = {
    headers: {
        'Accept':'application/json' 
    }
};

router.get('/bamboo/absencees', (req, res) => {

    const full_url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
    const search_params = full_url.searchParams;
    // const start = search_params.get('start')
    // const end = search_params.get('end')

    console.log("full url: ", fullUrl);
    console.log(end);
    console.log(sart);


    axios.get('https://'+bamboo_api_key+':x@api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/velocitypartners/v1/time_off/whos_out/'+req.query.params, config)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(req.query.params)
        res.send(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see `full_url` is just a concatenated string which obviously has no method/attribute `searchParams` like an object would have.

So we know that `full_url.searchParams` is undefined.
This would evaluate to

```
const search_params = undefined
```

which results in your problem.

Did you use a debugger? It would be helpful to see what `full_url` looks like during run-time. Nonetheless, it being a string should be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small thing, you need to know and add. `full_url`  is a string that doesn't have searchParams. So, make it a URL object and use their methods.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const router = require('express').Router();
const url = require('url');
require('dotenv').config();

const bamboo_api_key = process.env.BAMBOO_API_KEY;

const config = {
    headers: {
        'Accept':'application/json' 
    }
};

router.get('/bamboo/absencees', (req, res) => {

    const full_url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
   const myURL = new URL(full_url); // make it an URL object to use its methods
    const search_params = myURL.searchParams;
    const start = search_params.get('start')
    const end = search_params.get('end')

    console.log("full url: ", fullUrl);
    console.log(end);
    console.log(sart);



// you can use string literal here
  axios.get(`https://${bamboo_api_key}:x@api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/velocitypartners/v1/time_off/whos_out/${req.query.params}`  , config)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(req.query.params)
        res.send(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
})

module.exports = router;
```